# mentions/internal links in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a bunch of models. All these models has a method `get_absolute_url` and a field `text`. I want to make internal links in the `text` field just like wikipedia does.

Wikipedia's internal links in pages only refer to other pages. I need to link to all my models.

I could make a pattern for internal links and replacing this pattern with a hardcoded url to an url but it's really not a good idea because the links can change. So it would be best if I could refer to `get_absolute_url`.

Another option would be to use a template tag to change a specific pattern to links.

How should it be done? Are there any open source projects in which this has already been done?

Comment: can you give one use-case for your purpose? i dont really understand why you would want this

Comment: Like twitter, instagram, facebook and wikipedia. To point the users to other pages and see if a page is mentioned somewhere else on the page.

Comment: why are you making things so complex? just use named urls and you are fine!

Comment: But I want the users to link to other pages/users. So I can't use named urls.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to answer this same problem just a few days ago, and I did it with a template filter. My links are relative URLs, not absolute, but you could tweak that pretty easily, and you could also tweak the regex pattern to match whatever link markup you prefer.

Using the filter, the link is only looked up at display time, so if your view's URL has changed, that should automatically update with the `reverse()` lookup.

I also use Markdown to process my description fields, so I make the link return a markdown-formatted link instead of HTML, but you could tweak that too. If you use Markdown, you'd want to put this filter first.

So to display a description TextField with internal links, in the template would be something like this:

`{{ entity.description|internal_links|markdown }}`

(See the [Django docs on writing your own custom filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) for more details on writing and registering filters.)

As for the specific filter itself, I did it like this:

```
from django import template
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from my.views import *

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def internal_links(value):
    """
    Takes a markdown textfield, and filters
    for internal links in the format:

    {{film:alien-1979}}

    ...where "film" is the designation for a link type (model),
    and "alien-1979" is the slug for a given object

    NOTE: Process BEFORE markdown, as it will resolve
    to a markdown-formatted linked name:

    [Alien](http://opticalpodcast.com/cinedex/film/alien-1979/)

    :param value:
    :return:
    """
    try:
        import re
        pattern = '{{\S+:\S+}}'
        p = re.compile(pattern)
        #replace the captured pattern(s) with the markdown link
        return p.sub(localurl, value)
    except:
        # If the link lookup fails, just display the original text
        return value

def localurl(match):
    string = match.group()

    # Strip off the {{ and }}
    string = string[2:-2]

    # Separate the link type and the slug
    link_type, link_slug = string.split(":")
    link_view = ''

    # figure out what view we need to display
    # for the link type
    if(link_type == 'film'):
        link_view = 'film_detail'
    elif(link_type == 'person'):
        link_view = 'person_detail'
    else:
        raise Exception("Unknown link type.")

    link_url = reverse(link_view, args=(link_slug,))
    entity = get_object_or_404(Entity, slug=link_slug)
    markdown_link = "[" + entity.name + "](" + link_url + ")"

    return markdown_link
```

Comment: I also posted [a version on djangosnippets.org](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10420/) that resolves internal_links inside of markdown-formatted links, as well as on their own.